# SNS Mobile Push

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am currently developing an Android app in Xamarin. I am using AWS SNS Push and Google Cloud Messenger (GCM).

I've been following this walkthrough pretty closely:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/getting-started-sns-android.html

The code I've been working with is extremely similar to what's there. However, I have a Registration Intent Service that works as follows:

```
  [Service(Exported = false)]
  public class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
  {
    private static object locker = new object();

    public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") { }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Logging.LogMessage(Application, "RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken", LogType.Debug);
            lock (locker)
            {
                var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(Application.Context);
                Constants.token = instanceID.GetToken(
                    Constants.senderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                Logging.LogMessage(Application, "RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + Constants.token, LogType.Debug);
                /*SendRegistrationToAppServer(token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "Registered");*/

                SendRegistrationToAppServer(Constants.token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                Logging.LogMessage(Application, "RegistrationIntentService", "Registered", LogType.Debug);

                Subscribe(Constants.token);
            } // Release lock

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logging.LogMessage(Application, "RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token. Exception:\n" + e.ToString(), LogType.Error);
        }
    }

    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SendRegistrationToAppServer(string token)
    {
        var config = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig()
        {
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1
        };

        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.accessKeyId, Constants.secretAccessKey);

        Constants.client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(credentials, config);

        Logging.LogMessage(this, "RegistrationIntentService.SendRegistrationToAppServer", "Created client", LogType.Debug);

        if (Constants.createdEndpoint == null)
        {
            var endpoint = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest()
            {
                PlatformApplicationArn = Constants.endPoint,
                Token = token
            };

            var endpointResponse = await Constants.client.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(endpoint);
            Logging.LogMessage(this, "RegistrationIntentService.SendRegistrationToAppServer", "Got endpoint. ARN: " + endpointResponse.EndpointArn, LogType.Debug);
            Constants.createdEndpoint = endpointResponse.EndpointArn;
        }

        // Make sure we haven't subscribed yet
        if (Constants.createdEndpoint != null && Constants.subscriptionArn == null)
        {
            var subscription = await Constants.client.SubscribeAsync(Constants.topicARNBeginning + Constants.devicePhoneNumber, "Application", Constants.createdEndpoint);
            Logging.LogMessage(this, "RegistrationIntentService.SendRegistrationToAppServer", "AWS Subscribed", LogType.Debug);
        }
    }

    private bool Subscribe(string token)
    {
        var pubSub = GcmPubSub.GetInstance(Application.Context);
        const string topic = "/topics/global";

        try
        {
            pubSub.Subscribe(token, topic, null);
            Logging.LogMessage(this, "RegistrationIntentService.Subscribe", "GCM Subscribed", LogType.Debug);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Java.IO.IOException)
        {
            try
            {
                pubSub.Unsubscribe(token, topic);

                pubSub.Subscribe(token, topic, null);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException)
            {
                Logging.LogMessage(Application, "Subscribe", "Failed to register", LogType.Error);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I start the Registration Intent Service explicitly with a StartService() call in the MainActivity OnCreate event handler. I made sure I set up all of the permissions called for in the documentation:

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReceiveBootCompleted)]
[assembly: UsesPermission (Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission (Android.Manifest.Permission.WakeLock)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Vibrate)]
[assembly: UsesPermission("com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")]
[assembly: Permission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE", ProtectionLevel = Protection.Signature)]
[assembly: UsesPermission("@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission("com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")]
```

I create most of my Android Manifest through the AssemblyInfo.cs and appropriate C# Attributes (e.g. the [Service] attribute). The only thing I explicitly declare in XML (other than the application) is as follows:

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.gcmmessaging" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Here's the final manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" package="com.gcmmessaging" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<permission android:name="com.gcmmessaging.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.gcmmessaging.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<application android:name="mono.android.app.Application"
             android:allowBackup="true"
             android:debuggable="true"
             android:icon="@drawable/sns_icon_48"
             android:label="ProductName">
             <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
                    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                        <category android:name="com.gcmmessaging"/>
                    </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
            <activity android:name="[ConfigurationName]"
                        android:label="Configuration"/>
            <receiver android:name="md503b8085957a5cb3d4167d0e7cbb2a6b0.GCMBootReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <service android:name="md503b8085957a5cb3d4167d0e7cbb2a6b0.GCMIntentService" android:exported="false"/>
            <receiver android:name="md503b8085957a5cb3d4167d0e7cbb2a6b0.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <!-- It did occur to me to try to put all of these in a single  -->
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                    <category android:name="com.gcmmessaging"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                    <category android:name="com.gcmmessaging"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY"/>
                    <category android:name="com.gcmmessaging"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <activity android:name="[Activityname]" android:label="History"/>
            <service android:name="md503b8085957a5cb3d4167d0e7cbb2a6b0.MyInstanceIdListenerService" android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
            <activity android:name="[ActivityName]" android:icon="@drawable/sns_icon_32" android:label="ProductName">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <service android:name="md503b8085957a5cb3d4167d0e7cbb2a6b0.RegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false"/>
            <receiver android:name="md5343e36a1bb0d551a047a1a24886e23d0.NetworkReachability_NetworkStatusChangeBroadcastReceiver"/>
            <provider android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider" android:exported="false" android:authorities="com.gcmmessaging.google_measurement_service"/>
            <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" android:exported="false" android:enabled="true"/>
            <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver" android:enabled="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:authorities="com.gcmmessaging.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" android:initOrder="2147483647"/>
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU"/>
            <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.com.gcmmessaging"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my broadcast receiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] {
  "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"}, Categories = new string[] {
  "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] {
  "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"}, Categories = new string[] {
  "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] {
  "com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY"}, Categories = new string[] {
  "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver : WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
    //private const string TAG = "PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver";

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Logging.LogMessage(context, "GCMBroadcastReceiver.OnReceive", "Received message", LogType.Debug);

        GCMIntentService.RunIntentInService(context, intent);
        SetResult(Result.Ok, null, null);

        Logging.LogMessage(context, "GCMBroadcastReceiver.OnReceive", "Ran intent service", LogType.Debug);
    }
}
```

I currently receive a GCM token and subscribe to GCM and SNS correctly. I checked the return codes there carefully and I'm definitely getting a valid-looking GCM token and my subscription shows up in SNS. My call to subscribe to GCM succeeds without throwing any exceptions. However, I don't actually receive any pushes. I know for a fact that AWS is, in fact, publishing the data (if I create an email subscription I receive everything I'm sending out). I also know that the issues aren't caused by my corporate firewall - if I try to do it over 4G it fails too.

I do get the two following errors in my logs:
03-11 16:33:08.914 E/GcmReceiver( 7749): Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
03-11 16:33:08.914 E/GcmReceiver( 7749): Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.

I'm not sure if these are the cause or not. I haven't been able to find a good resolution to these online yet.

Anyone have any suggestions on what to try (or how to go about debugging this)? I'm truthfully at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: And where is your receiver service? you need a service derived from GcmListenerService with an intent filter of type com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE. The fail states it can't find the class for that service.

Comment: I did have an implementation that used that as well but it didn't seem to help. Do I need to have both that and a broadcast receiver though? My broadcast receiver is already receiving intents of those type and passes it to my intent service.

Comment: But you didn't posted the code for the broadcast receiver, and the broadcast receiver is the one which receives the messages, so if you have an error it should be there.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, I edited to include that code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing API's, for one side you use the new InstanceId API to get the token and in other you use the old way of receiving data with a wakefulbroadcastreceiver, replace your receiver with a derived type from GcmListenerService, something like this:

```
[Service (Exported = false), IntentFilter (new [] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
public class SignalGCMReceiver : GcmListenerService
{

    public override void OnMessageReceived (string from, Bundle data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());

    }
}
```

And finally add the receiver on the manifest (the receiver is implemented internally by the service):

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="@PACKAGE_NAME@" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```