# AWS SNS notifications to GCM not working

Tags: java, amazon-sns

I am trying to send SNS notification to my app using a GCM endpoint.

The message is as follows

```
{"default":"notification 7","GCM":"{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"notification 7\" } }"}
```

It is showing success on the cloudwatch log. But message does not reach the device. Any setting that i am forgetting?

This is the snippet of my code

```
    static {
    try {
        ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =  new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider(Constants.APPPROPERTIESFILE);
            snsClient =  (AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider.getCredentials()))).build();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Some exception " + e);
    }
    }

    PublishResult snsres = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
```

I get a message id and success as returned value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SNS Mobile Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949757/sns-mobile-push)

Comment: Plz provide what code you're trying, see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I have edited and added all my attempts. Please unblock the q as i need a solution desperately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time. The json format was wrong. The data property has a string value rather than a json. Hence I did a jsonobj.toString() and the notifications worked. Not only that, I can now add any custom property value I need to.

Comment: Can you check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971567/aws-sns-push-for-gcm-showing-as-sent-from-cloudwatch-but-not-received-in-mobil ? I am facing similar issue and not sure about how to make it work?